# Does the new CameraX api provide multi-camera support for processing dual camera streams separately?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-camerax

I want to build an application for taking photos with both cameras of a dual cam at the same time and wanted to ask if someone knows if the new camerax api allows me to process both camera streams separately.

Comment: Any news on this front?  I was hoping to delve into a few multi-camera applications and I would like to know if onboarding into camerax is a waste of time or not.

Comment: Not that i know of or even if its on their radar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see, CameraX does not support multi-camera API yet, at least not as of 1.0.0-alpha08. They just added a new experimental API to get the cameraID for now, but that's about it.

See https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/camera#camera-core-1.0.0-alpha08

Comment: Do you have any links for the "API to get the cameraID"? I can't find a way to select a Camera by it's ID, there's only the `CameraSelector::requiresLensFacing` BS...